# ionic / angular2 - (tap) does not work (inside element with (tap)), (click) fires automatically

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, styles

I have some HTML that looks like this. I am using Ionic:

```
<ion-item class="changepadding" *ngFor="let j of items ; let i = index" (tap)='expandItem(i)' id='{{i}}' #feedstyle text-wrap>
      <div class="flex" #flex>
        <div class="nonzoomimage">
          <img class="imagepost" src="{{j.url}}">
        </div>
        <div class="descholder">
          <div class='description'>{{j.title}}</div>
          <div class='link'>{{j.date}}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="feedtoptextcontainer" #feedtop (tap)='contractItem(i)'>
        <div class="imageparent">
          <img class="postprofilepic" src="{{j.profilepic}}">
        </div>
        <div class="usernamecontainer">
          <h4 class="postusername">@{{j.username}}</h4><br>
          <h4 class="poststudio">Ed's Studio</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="postprofilelink">
          <div class="book">{{j.title}}</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <img class="imageposttwo" #imagepost src="{{j.url}}">
      <div class='caption' #caption>
        {{j.caption}}
      <br>
      </div>
     </ion-item>
```

Here is the `contractItem` function - this is the `(tap)` that won't respond:

```
contractItem(item) {
    console.log("in contract item 8*****");
    let flexArray = this.flexComponents.toArray();
    let feedArray = this.feedComponents.toArray();
    let itemArray = this.components.toArray();
    let imageComps = this.imageComponents.toArray();
    let captionComps = this.captionComponents.toArray();


    this.myrenderer.setElementStyle(flexArray[item].nativeElement, 'display', 'flex');
    this.myrenderer.setElementStyle(flexArray[item].nativeElement, 'padding', '4px 4px 0px 4px');
    this.myrenderer.setElementStyle(feedArray[item].nativeElement, 'display', 'none');
    //flexArray[item].nativeElement.style = 'display: none';
    //feedArray[item].nativeElement.style = 'display: flex';
    this.myrenderer.setElementStyle(imageComps[item].nativeElement, 'display', 'none');
    this.myrenderer.setElementStyle(captionComps[item].nativeElement, 'display', 'none');
    //imageComps[item].nativeElement.style = 'display: block';
    this.myrenderer.setElementStyle(itemArray[item]._elementRef.nativeElement, 'padding', '0');
    //itemArray[item]._elementRef.nativeElement.style = "padding: 0";
    //this.myrenderer.setElementAttribute(itemArray[item]._elementRef.nativeElement, 'no-padding', '');
    //this.myrenderer.setElementAttribute(itemArray[item]._elementRef.nativeElement, 'no-lines', '');
    //var selectedRow = document.getElementById('item');
    //console.log(selectedRow);
  }
```

The `console.log` message at the top doesn't get output when I tap the area with `(tap)='contractItem(i)'`. Initially, `.feedtoptextcontainer` is not visible...it is only visible after `(tap)='expandItem'` is tapped.
How do I get the `div` with `contractItem` to be tappable? Also, if I use `(click)` instead of `(tap)` `expandItem` works and then it immediately contracts as if `contractItem` was tapped.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ion-item use button with the ion-item attribute.

```
<button ion-item (click)="buttonClick()">
  Button Item
</button>
```